# Query data in one table based on IDs from another

Tags: mysql, sql, database, roundcube

I'm trying to export data from Roundcube, and it has 2 tables that I need, the users and contacts. Currently I'm using this to filter the users:

```
 SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE "%mysite.com%"
```

But how do I export data from the contacts table, where the `user_id` matches the above filtered list of `user_id`s? Do I have to use temporary tables? I've never done a join. I don't want a pretty listing of the 2 tables joined, I want to export the data using a `SELECT` clause to filter it and re-import it, so I need the data in the original format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use sub-queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM `contacts`
WHERE `user_id` IN (
    SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE "%mysite.com%"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the tables are related via the `user_id` you can join on them:

```
SELECT c.* 
FROM `users` u
INNER JOIN `contacts` c
    on u.`user_id` = c.`user_id` 
WHERE u.`username` LIKE "%mysite.com%"
```

If you need help learning join syntax here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)